# Why is "$f(A\cap f^{-1}(B))=f(A)\cap B$" true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A bit of context: I was reading the proof of the following statement:
"let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous and proper mapping where $Y$ is T2 and compactly generated, then $f$ is closed".
At the end of the proof you use the fact that "$f(C\cap f^{-1}(K))=f(C)\cap K$" where $C$ is a closed subset of $X$ and $K$ is a compact subset of $Y$.
My question is: why is "$f(C\cap f^{-1}(K))=f(C)\cap K$" true? The inclusion "$\subseteq$" is trivial, but i don't know how to show the other one.
PS: I'm sorry if something is wrong with the English, it's not my native language!

Comment: If $f(c) \in K$ then $c \in f^{-1}(K)$.  Use that on the lefthand set.

Comment: The statement in the title is true for subsets of the domain and codomain of any function, regardless of which topological or other structure they may have.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic "unwind the definitions and follow your nose" proof.

To prove the other inclusion, let $k\in f(C)\cap K$. Then there exists $c\in C$ such that $f(c)=k$, which is in $K$. Since $f(c)\in K$, then $c\in f^{-1}(K)$. Thus, $c\in C\cap f^{-1}(K)$.

Hence $k=f(c)\in f(C\cap f^{-1}(K))$, which is what we needed to prove.

Note that this is an argument purely at the set-and-functions level. Despite the context in which you encountered the assertion, the topological assumptions play no role.